# how to detect tcp connection lost while internet connection lost for 5 sec in the ios

Tags: ios

I am using socket connection in my app. The app is working fine while the connection is fine.

While the internet is gone for 5 seconds and comes back then I am not able to detect immediately connection is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use heartbeat package to detect if there is a connection! and reconnect or handle error when connection lost.

Comment: Can you please send me any link of heartbeat package?